# Can't bind properly DataGrid and ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Just started working with WPF and I am trying to work with the data grid and ObservableCollection with binding the data between them and I got a few questions about that subject:

1. I did a binding to the ItemsSource on the XAML file to the cs ObservableCollection property and when I did it through the XAML I didn't see any data displayed in the DataGrid but when I did this:

   mainWindow_myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbData

(mainWindow_myDataGrid is the XAML DataGrid , dbData is ObservableCollection property)
it worked and I don't have a clue why.

2. When I did the binding through the code `(mainWindow_myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbData)`
   . I didn't use the `DataGridTextColumn` view in the XAML file and I saw the data in it. But when I did used it, it crashed with an error that says

> "error when adding a row",

then again I have no clue why.

I firstly tried to find answers on my self of course with no success. If anyone could clear those points to me that would be great!

Comment: You need to post your code here before anyone can help you out.

Comment: Please post the minimun code necesary to see what you tried.

Comment: what is dbData? Please post your code and xaml so that we can try help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you have code like this: mainWindow_myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbData then you do NOT any kind of binding. you simply set the itemssource. you dont post enough code but i will give you an example

when you wanna use binding you need a public property

```
  public OberservableCollection<YourDataType> MyCollection {get;set;}
```

fill your collection and set the DataContext to the object(viewmodel) with your Collection. create your Binding in XAML

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
```

thats all.

if this dont work then most time the DataContext is not right or the Binding Expression is wrong. you can check this at runtime with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)